# wpf height and width by element binding

Tags: wpf, grid, tabcontrol, rowdefinition, element-binding

wpf height and width of control based on rowheight and rowwidth of grid by
**element binding** to it.

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="170" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"   x:Name="ContentControlRow"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="170"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Tab" MaxHeight="{Binding   ElementName=ContentControlRow, Path=ActualHeight}" Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TabItem>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

In the above code it is taking MaxHeight=0. But what i need is it should take that based on ContentControlRow's Height and it should be variable based on Window size.

Comment: set Path=Height instead of ActualHeight

Comment: Thank you. Its working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change ActualHeight to Height in Binding.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="170" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"   x:Name="ContentControlRow"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="170"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Tab" MaxHeight="{Binding   ElementName=ContentControlRow, Path=Height}" Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TabItem>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
</Grid>
```